# VirtualHost not working?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, virtualhost

**The problem:**

On my local machine only, I want to enter the URL homepage.local and I want it to open my local webpage `index.html` found in my local directory `/Users/prime/Homepage/`. I thought I could achieve this by using the below vhost configuration but it doesn't seem to work.

Added the following to my httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName homepage.local
    ServerAlias *.homepage.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/prime/Homepage/"
</VirtualHost>
```

and when I go to my web-browser and enter the URL `homepage.local` it does not resolve to my webpage `/Users/prime/Homepage/index.html`

Any ideas? I can't see anything in the apache error logs.

```
$ apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   homepage.local (/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:533)
```

I am on OSX (Snow Leopard).

Comment: Is `homepage.local` actually pointing to your local machine? Did you set up the DNS or hosts entries? Does it show the local IP (127.0.0.1) when you do `ping homepage.local`?

Comment: @Pekka: The `.local` pseudo-TLD is supplied by Avahi/Zeroconf, which is configured by default on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up your host file? Server name directive does nothing unless the network resolves to the server properly.

You can edit your hosts file by following these directions [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27291). Except you want to keep the ip address the same and just change the name to `homepage.local`.